# OSError while updating pytorch

Tags: python, django, apache, unix, chown

When I tried to update my pytorch version to 0.4 using the following command line

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.0 -c pytorch
```

I got the following error:

```
Solving environment: done

##Package Plan## 

environment location: /anaconda

added / updated specs: 
- pytorch=0.4.0


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

blas:         1.0-mkl                              
intel-openmp: 2018.0.3-0                           
libcxx:       4.0.1-h579ed51_0                     
libcxxabi:    4.0.1-hebd6815_0                     
libgfortran:  3.0.1-h93005f0_2                     
mkl_fft:      1.0.4-py27h5d10147_1                 
mkl_random:   1.0.1-py27h5d10147_1                 
ninja:        1.8.2-py27h04f5b5a_1                 
numpy-base:   1.15.0-py27h8a80b8c_0                
pytorch:      0.4.0-py27_cuda0.0_cudnn0.0_1 pytorch

The following packages will be UPDATED:

mkl:          2017.0.3-0                            --> 2018.0.3-1           
numpy:        1.13.1-py27_0                         --> 1.15.0-py27h648b28d_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::numpy-1.13.1-py27_0'.
OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

I saw online that I should use the chown functionality but I am not sure how to use it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Unless multiple users using same anaconda environment, you should have installed anaconda to your home directory, but here is a quickfix, in terminal type:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /anaconda
```

Then update your conda, this command will transfer ownership of anaconda directory at the root to your user. If multiple users needs to use same anaconda environment, follow these steps

```
#  create a new user group  
sudo groupadd anacondausers
#  add all users to group
sudo usermod -a -G anacondausers USER1
sudo usermod -a -G anacondausers USER2
#  make your group owner of folder
sudo chown -R :anacondausers /anaconda
```